# Why did only 12 people survive the Kurukshetra War?

Tags: war, kurukshetra

Only 12 people survived the Kurukshetra War: the five Pandavas, Krishna, Satyaki, Ashwatthama, Kripacharya, Yuyutsu, Vrishaketu, and Kritvarma. How is this possible? In a war of approximately 3.94 million warriors according to [this source](https://www.scoopwhoop.com/inothernews/characters-who-survived-kurukshetra-war-mahabharata/), only 12 survived?

Comment: because making sure everyone else was dead was Krishna's avatara goal.

Comment: The source you reference says 12 characters that survived...it does not say "only" that 12 survived. You have misquoted your source.

Answer (score 2):

There were ten people who survived the war.

Five Pandavas, Vasudeva, Satyaki,  Ashvatthama, Kripa and Kritavarma

Ashvathama said that ten people survived. Seven from the Pandavas and three from Kauravas

> "If, O Duryodhana, thou hast
> any life in thee still, listen to these words that are so pleasant to
> hear. **On the side of the Pandavas, only seven are alive, and among the
> Dhartarashtras, only we three! The seven on their side are the five
> brothers and Vasudeva and Satyaki; on our side, we three are myself
> and Kripa and Kritavarma**! All the sons of Draupadi have been slain, as
> also all the children of Dhrishtadyumna! All the Pancalas too have
> been slain, as also the remnant of the Matsyas, O Bharata! Behold the
> vengeance taken for what they had done! The Pandavas are now
> childless! While buried in sleep, the men and animals in their camp
> have all been slain! Penetrating into their camp in the night, O king,
> I have slain Dhrishtadyumna, that wight of sinful deeds, as one kills
> an animal."
>
> [[Section 9, Sauptika Parva, The Mahabharata]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10009.htm)

Dhritarashtra tells how many people survived the war

> 'Alas! **I have heard that the war hath left only ten alive: three of
> our side, and the Pandavas, seven, in that dreadful conflict eighteen
> Akshauhinis of Kshatriyas have been slain**! All around me is utter
> darkness, and a fit of swoon assaileth me: consciousness leaves me, O
> Suta, and my mind is distracted."
>
> [[Section I, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01002.htm)